# volume of the area between cylinder and planes

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

For the volume of the area bounded by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2y$ and planes $z=0$ and $x+y+z=7$. I know that volume of the area is $\iiint dxdydz$ but I couldnt find the boundaries of the integral. Can anyone help with that?

Comment: I think the cylinder should have $2z$ instead of $2y$ right? Also, do you know polar coordinates and how to change to polar coordinates in integral?

Comment: its not 2z. Yes i know but how can i use polar coordinates on this question

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Cylindrical polar coordinates, i.e. $\space x=\rho \cos \varphi, y = \rho \sin \varphi, z = z, J = \rho, \\ 0 \le \rho \le 2\sin \varphi, 0 \le \varphi \le \pi, 0 \le z \le 7 - \rho\cos \varphi - \rho \sin  \varphi.$

**Figure:**

[image]

Comment: it helped so much! thank you

Comment: You are welcome @Sameen Shaw.